# Laravel Brower Test (Dusk) error on MacOS (Docker): Failed to connect on localhost port 9515: connection refused

Tags: laravel

I just installed Laravel's Dusk to add browser tests. However, when I run a test, I get a `Failed to connect on localhost port 9515: connection refused` error.

I checked online and it seems like a lot of people are having the same issue. I came across few solutions e.g. [this](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/50#issuecomment-275155974) but it seems like they are all for Windows and Homestead whilst I am running my project on MacOS and Docker.

I did try to follow the solution but I found out `sudo apt` is not available for MacOS. I then installed Homebrew and tried to run the commands starting with `brew` instead of `sudo apt` but it responds saying no formula available for the name.

I would really appreciate it if you could recommend a solution or source I could look at. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone else is having the same issue:

Basically, the issue was I was just following the [Laravel Dusk Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk) without making any further configuration.

For the Docker environment, more configuration has to be done such as adding a Selenium container to allow the browser tests to run.

Checkout Jake Harris's [7 steps to running Laravel Dusk 3.0 tests in Docker environments](https://medium.com/@scuttlebyte/running-headless-laravel-dusk-3-0-tests-in-docker-environments-f396752a9ffe) to do this.

Thank you.